# App usage history

Tags: applications

I'm trying to find out how to check my Application Usage History of this phone. 4636 Does not work, and other applications in play store only start monitoring the app history once installed. I uninstalled an application last 2018 but I want to know how many hours I used on the application, and when I last opened it. Is there an application that can see that?